# error in opening jar file rt.jar jdeveloper Oracle Middleware

Tags: java, jvm, middleware, jdeveloper

I'm developing a project with web services in JAVA, in JDEV.

I'm using Oracle Middleware and I am getting this error when trying to run every time:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar
Process exited with exit code 1.

I've found people with the same issue, but apparently no fix so far:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3783771?start=0&tstart=0

My workaround is to copy and paste the .jar in my local project folder.
But is pretty annoying to do this everytime I want to run.
It works after doing it, so I'm sticking to that for now.

I'm using Windows and my app does not "crash" when running in a Web Logic Server so I'm thinking is something in my laptop.

The .jar is fine, and is not 0kb.

Answer (score 1):

Modify access control of the rt.jar file in windows.
Give full control to the windows logged in user.

Comment: I checked the file and currently all users including admin and me have all kinds of permissions on this file., but still with the VM error